# Add a dynamic ruby generated id to a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a script on a html.erb file.

To cut a long story short I have this line in the script

```
   $('img:gt(0)').hide();
```

I want to add a dynamic id to the img selector. The dynamic id is

```
    <%= hrct.id %>
```

I've tried

```
                var imgVar = <%= hrct.id %>;
                $('#img_+ imgVar img:gt(0)').hide();
```

No good.

And

```
                var imgVar = <%= hrct.id %>;
                $('#img_+ (imgVar) img:gt(0)').hide();
```

No good.

Help?

EDIT: I have now tried

```
                  $(function(){
                    var imgVar = <%= hrct.id %>;
                    $('#img_'+ imgVar +' img:gt(0)').hide(); // to hide all but the first image when page loads
                    var img = $('#<%= hrct.id %>').children(), l = img.length;
                    $('#Up, #Down').on('click', function() {
                      var i = img.index( img.filter(':visible').hide() );
                      var t = this.id === 'Up' ? ++i : --i;
                      img.eq( t === l ? 0 : t ).show();
                    });
                  });
```

I have included the full function. If you look at the developer tools you get

[image]

instead of

```
        $('#img_3 img:gt(0)').hide();
```

In fact,

```
       $('#img_<%= hrct.id %> img:gt(0)').hide();
```

Gives

```
       $('#img_3 img:gt(0)').hide();
```

But the function doesn't work as it should

Comment: Hi, Have you tried `$('#img_'+ imgVar +' img:gt(0)').hide();` ?

Comment: That resulted in   $('#img_'+ imgVar +' img:gt(0)').hide(); when viewed in the html. In other words, the imgVar isn't converted to the variable, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: What do you mean, "isn't converted to the variable"?

Comment: See the comment above. Many thanks for the time

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var imgVar = <%= "#img_#{hrct.id}" %>;
$(imgVar +' img:gt(0)').hide();
```

I hope this would be helpfulf

Comment: Still no luck. The issue is the img:gt(0) part. If I wanted just a dynamic id then it would be easy. Its combining the dynamic id with the all images greater than 0 syntac thats the problem. Many thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Change this row (Expecting **#img_**)

```
var img = $('#<%= hrct.id %>').children()
```

to:

```
var img = $('#img_<%= hrct.id %>').children()
```